# Pyspark - Selecting rows in dataframe based on values that exist in another dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Assume these two pyspark `dataframes`:

`dfA`

```
id
1
2
3
4
```

`dfB`

```
src,dst
2  ,3
1  ,3
3  ,4
4  ,1
7  ,3
1  ,8
```

How can I get this desired output:

`resultDf`

```
src,dst
2  ,3
1  ,3
3  ,4
4  ,1
```

Basically I want to select `Rows` from `dfB` that contain a value of `dfA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the desired result using `spark.sql`

```
resultDf = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM dfA WHERE dfB.src IN (SELECT * FROM dfA) AND dfB.dst IN (SELECT * FROM dfA)")
```